How to conditionally add a term query to a Elasticsearch Data Elasticsearch repository using the @Query annotation and SpEl?
I'm trying to integrate an existing legacy application to Elasticsearch using Spring Data Elasticsearch (version 5.3.0). I wrote a repository like this:

public interface IndexableUserRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<IndexableUser, Integer> {

  @Query(
    """
          {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                 #{#user.hasNeverPrintedUserCard ? '' :
                  '{
                    "term": {
                      "hasPrintedUserCard": false
                    }
                  },'
                }
                {
                  "term": {
                    "isInactive": #{#user.isInactive}
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
  """)
  Page<IndexableUser> findByQueryWithName(
          IndexableUserQueryParameters user, PageRequest pageRequest);
}

(I'll omit the definition of IndexableUserQueryParameters and IndexableUser for the sake of brevity.)
I want to include a term query conditionally on the hasPrintedUserCard property of the record IndexableUserQueryParameters being false. In other words,

if the hasPrintedUserCard is false, include the term query to only include the documents that have the hasPrintedUserCard field set to false.
if the hasPrintedUserCard is true don't include the term query, so include documents regardless of the value of hasPrintedUserCard.

However, the double quotes around "term" and "hasPrintedUserCard" are being escaped, which causes a syntax error for Elasticsearch.
I decoded the wrapped query value and got this
{
  "bool": {
    "filter": [
       {
          \"term\": {
            \"hasPrintedUserCard\": false
          }
        },
      {
        "term": {
          "isInactive": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


Is that the expected behavior for SpEl? Or is it an issue with how the @Query annotation works? Is there a way to implement that conditional inclusion of a term query using @Query + @SpEl?
I tried removing the single quotes from around the term query, but it then gave me an error detected by Spring itself about SpEl syntax.
